# Crop detected face using eye position as reference

Tags: opencv, crop, face-recognition, eye-detection

Does anybody know a method to crop a detected face using the eye position as a reference? I need to crop a detected face in a video stream in order to perform a face recognition with a better reliability. I've seen the haar cascade for the eye position but it's too chaotic and It needs filtering for the false positive (thing that I can't do without lowering the performance of my program)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: http://answers.opencv.org/question/24670/how-can-i-align-face-images/#24845

Answer (score 1):

After detecting the face you can set the ROI (region of interest) to the upper half of the detected rectangle (also reduce the width a little) and perform the eye localization only there.

That will reduce the false positives.